# TL2017 broke my boxes

Tags: boxes, latex3, texlive-2017

This pertains to LaTeX3 and the changes introduced in TL2017.

I'm defining a command that constructs a box but I need to put something in at the start of the box.  So I look ahead for the opening brace, absorb it from the stream, do the extra stuff I want to do, then start the box with a `\c_group_begin_token`.

This worked in TL2016 but TL2017 complains.

Specifically, the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\box_new:N \l__tmpa_box

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \dobox
{
  \exp_after:wN \dobox_aux: \tex_let:D \l_peek_token =
}

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \dobox_aux:
{
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__tmpa_box
  \c_group_begin_token
  in~the~box~
}

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \dobebox
{
  \box_use:N \l__tmpa_box
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

greetings
\dobox{hello world}
everyone
\dobebox

\end{document}
```

compiles in TL2016 producing the output:

```
greetings  everyone in the box hello world
```

but in TL2017, I get a complaint:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.32 \dobox
           {hello world}
? 
! Too many }'s.
l.32 \dobox{hello world}

?
```

and the output produced is:

```
greetings in the box hello world everyone
```

showing that the box construction is ignored.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What is `\expandafter\doboxaux\let\whatever= ` supposed to do? Answer: nothing different from `\doboxaux\let\whatever= `. Are you sure you don't want `\afterassignment`?

Comment: @egreg (what's the l3 version of `\afterassignment`?)  I still get the same error with the `\c_begin_group_token` though.

Comment: There's none. And I explain in my answer the reason for the error.

Comment: You have `\hbox_set:Nw \l_tmpa_box ... \hbox_set_end:`. In any case I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, and it seems that there has to be another way. Perhaps you could explain. Why can't you use (in expl3 code, of course) `\def\dobox#1{\setbox\foo=\hbox{in the box #1}}`?

Comment: Ah, may be `\catcode`s.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, catcodes are the key.  I want to put some stuff in a box, but I don't want to freeze the catcodes by reading it into an argument.

Answer (score 13):

A translation in standard TeX code:

```
\newbox\mybox

\def\dobox{%
  \expandafter\doboxaux\let\mytoken =%
}

\def\doboxaux{%
  \setbox\mybox=\hbox\bgroup in the box
}

\def\dobebox{%
  \copy\mybox
}
```

Note that `\expandafter` will do nothing at all. When you call

```
\dobox{hello world}
```

the macro `\doboxaux` is immediately expanded and you get

```
\setbox\mybox=\hbox\bgroup in the box \let\mytoken={hello world}
```

The `{` is gobbled by `\let\mytoken=`, so the box will contain “hello world”.

The result will be

> greetings in the box hello world everyone

However, `\hbox_set:Nn \l__tmpa_box` is *very* different from `\setbox\mybox=\hbox`. The latter accepts `\bgroup` (in `expl3` lingo `\c_begin_group_token`) the former doesn't, because it is a two argument function and an `n` argument cannot be delimited by `\bgroup`.

The fact that it may have in the past is irrelevant. You're abusing `expl3`. Here's what `\cs_show:N \hbox_set:Nn` yields

```
> \hbox_set:Nn=\protected\long macro:#1#2->\tex_setbox:D #1\tex_hbox:D
{\group_begin: #2\group_end: }.
```

so you see that `#2` is grabbed as a normal argument. Your (wrong) macros used to work because `#2` is `\c_group_begin_token`. The effect is very similar to what you get in LaTeX2e with `\mbox\bgroup foo\egroup` that seems to work, but actually doesn't. The definition of `\hbox_set:Nn` has changed and the (wrong) concoction now raises an error.

You probably wanted to do

```
\def\dobox{%
  \afterassignment\doboxaux\let\mytoken=
}

\def\doboxaux{%
  \setbox\mybox=\hbox\bgroup in the box
}

\def\dobebox{%
  \copy\mybox
}
```

Alas, `expl3` doesn't provide an interface to `\afterassignment`.

Comment: I think I can cope with breaking out to ordinary TeX here.  I might use a few judicious `\let`s to make all the command names have underscores just for the look of the thing.  Thanks for the analysis.